# Datagrid Scrollbar not showing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, datagrid, compact-framework, smart-device

I'm writing a smart device application for a Windows CE 6.0 Device on VS 2008 with Compact Framework 3.5. I am using a dataGrid (Not dataGridView) to get data from a Database.

I'm having problems with my dataGrid's scrollbar. When I run the application on the VS Emulator the vertical scrollbar is visible but when I deploy it onto the actual device and try, then it isn't visible and I'm not able to see all the rows.

Could someone please help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

For the **dataGrid** the scroll bars appers when the height or width exceeds the screen. Note that the height and width in pixels are diferent in emulator and device. Calculate based on screen in runtime. Like following code.

```
public static int CalcPixels(double percent, Form form)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32((percent / 100) * form.Width);
}
```